# Product of Integrals: Seemingly simple problem

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral

I am an Engineer by profession and it has been a long time since I studied Mathematics. I am still confident with my basic skills in Engineering / Applied Maths. Recently, I started tutoring / mentoring a couple of kids in the neighborhood with whatever skills I still possess. They bought me this problem and I am completely stumped.

Any guidance on how to proceed will be greatly appreciated.

$$ Evaluate \left \{ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left ( sin\theta  \right )^{\frac{3}{4}}d\theta \right \}\cdot\left \{ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left ( sin\theta  \right )^{-\frac{3}{4}}d\theta \right \} $$

Comment: These are Beta integrals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown  Thank you. I'll look into it. 
Why can't we multiply the two integrands and make it a double integral? Is there a specific reason? I know we can't do that but I am trying to understand the reasoning behind that.

Comment: @Guillermo Mosse Thank you so much. Yes, I do remember. I think I was overthinking things.

Comment: You *can* write this as a double integral:$$\left \{ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left ( sin\theta  \right )^{\frac{3}{4}}d\theta \right \}\cdot\left \{ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left ( sin\theta  \right )^{-\frac{3}{4}}d\theta \right \} = \left \{ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left ( sin\theta  \right )^{\frac{3}{4}}d\theta \right \}\cdot\left \{ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left ( sin\phi  \right )^{-\frac{3}{4}}d\phi \right \} \\= \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \left[ \frac{\sin \theta}{\sin \phi} \right]^{3/4} \, d \theta \, d \phi.$$ But that's not much easier to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a>-1$,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^a t\,dt=\frac12 B((a+1)/2,1/2)
=\frac{\Gamma(a/2+1/2)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(a/2+1)}
=\frac{\sqrt\pi\Gamma((a+1)/2)}{2\Gamma(a/2+1)}
$$
where $B$ and $\Gamma$ denote the beta and gamma functions.
Your product is
$$\frac{\sqrt\pi\Gamma(1/8)}{2\Gamma(5/8)}
\frac{\sqrt\pi\Gamma(7/8)}{2\Gamma(11/8)}
=\frac{\pi\Gamma(1/8)\Gamma(7/8)}{4(3/8)\Gamma(5/8)\Gamma(3/8)}
=\frac{2\pi\sin(3\pi/8)}{3\sin(\pi/8)}
=\frac{2\pi}3\tan(3\pi/8)
=\frac{2\pi(\sqrt2+1)}{3}.$$

Comment: Thanks again. I was able to get to the solution after getting reacquainted with Beta Functions. 

So basically, we are taking $cos^0(t)$ in the integral, right? After that I arrived at the same answer as yours. Thanks so much for the help and guidance.